# Trouble With Recursion/Enumerations

Tags: java, enumeration

I am currently trying to write a code for a party pong game in java.  The deal is, each team has 2 players.  If one player makes a cup, it is removed.  If both players make a cup, two are removed and they get one bonus shot.  If neither player makes a cup, they have to remove one of their cups.  This way, the game always ends.  The goal is to return an arraylist of how many different possible ways there are to win for each team, given a certain amount of cups to start out with for each team, like 1 or 2.  I am struggling with figuring out how to write incursions to make this task easier.  Its suppose to output something like this:

```
[Folder]% java PartyPong 0
Team 1 Wins: 
[Folder]% java PartyPong 1
Team 1 Wins: 1:A 
Team 1 Wins: 1:B 
Team 2 Wins: 1:X 
[Folder]% java PartyPong 2
Team 1 Wins: 1:A 2:A 1:A 
Team 1 Wins: 1:A 2:A 1:B 
Team 2 Wins: 1:A 2:A 1:X 
Team 1 Wins: 1:A 2:B 1:A 
Team 1 Wins: 1:A 2:B 1:B 
Team 2 Wins: 1:A 2:B 1:X 
Team 2 Wins: 1:A 2:AB 
Team 1 Wins: 1:A 2:X 
Team 1 Wins: 1:B 2:A 1:A 
Team 1 Wins: 1:B 2:A 1:B 
Team 2 Wins: 1:B 2:A 1:X 
Team 1 Wins: 1:B 2:B 1:A 
Team 1 Wins: 1:B 2:B 1:B 
Team 2 Wins: 1:B 2:B 1:X 
Team 2 Wins: 1:B 2:AB 
Team 1 Wins: 1:B 2:X 
Team 1 Wins: 1:AB 
Team 2 Wins: 1:X 2:A 
Team 2 Wins: 1:X 2:B 
Team 1 Wins: 1:X 2:X 1:A 
Team 1 Wins: 1:X 2:X 1:B 
Team 2 Wins: 1:X 2:X 1:X
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction with how to make incursions and make this easier?? Thanks

Comment: When you say incursion you mean recursion right?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this psuedocode

```
//input an empty list, after the function is done the list is populated

function combosLeft(cupsA as Number, 
                    cupsB as Number, 
                    list as List<List<String>>, //passed by reference (gets populated)
                    soFar as List<String>) //passed by reference

    if neither player ran out of cups then
                temp as List<String>
                temp := clone(sofar)
                push_onto(temp, "A")
                combosLeft(cupsA - 1, cupsB, temp, list) //recursion
                temp := clone(sofar)
                push_onto(temp, "B")
                combosLeft(cupsA, cupsB - 1, temp, list) //recursion
                temp := clone(sofar)
                push_onto(temp, "AB")
                combosLeft(cupsA - 1, cupsB - 1, temp, list) //recursion
    otherwise
                push_onto(list, sofar)
    end if
end function
```

You can create a wrapper function too for convenience

```
function combosLeft(cupsA as Number, cupsB as Number) as List<List<String>>
        list as List<List<String>>
        soFar as List<String>
        combosLeft(cupsA, cupsB, list, soFar)
        return list
    end function
```

If you need more hints just let me know. Good Luck :)

Comment: it is psuedo code since i do not want to just give you the answer...its just as good as any other code...its up to you to convert it